# How to remove unused tables in the database in Drupal 7

Tags: database

Is there an easy way to detect tables that are no longer used by my Drupal installation? I find it annoying that tables from previously used modules remain. I'll simply drop them using phpMyAdmin if not, but its a bit of a pain, and involves backing it up for obvious reasons! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) will tell you that.
If a module leaves tables after uninstall, that's a bug, and you should open an issue.

Comment: Schema's advice should be taken with a grain of salt. It can have both false positive and false negative results. For example, it may mark all field data as unused tables. It is the right tool for this job though.

Answer (score 1):

After disabling and before removing the module run drush pm-uninstall 'modulename' in the terminal.([More info on drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush)) 
Or through the website go to /admin/modules/uninstall.
The name of the module will still be found in the 'system' table, this can be deleted manually.

Comment: Why the name of the module will still be found in system table? Isn't drush pm-uninstall - uninstalling everything? I have noticed myself this thing either, after every use of pm-uninstall, the module name remains in the system table. What reason to use pm-uninstall then?

Comment: Calling uninstall deletes all module related tables from the DB. It also calls hook_uninstall which can delete module specific settings. The module still exists in the system directory because the module is available in the modules directory. However, its status is set to disabled.

Comment: So if i delete it from /sites/all/modules it's going to dissapear in the system table you say?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but would say yes. If the module is uninstalled properly and the module is removed from sites/all/modules the entry in the system table can be safely deleted. If not automatically, if cvan be done manually.

Comment: Well, thanks for your explanations i'm going to check this out.